# Очистка  средствами javascript

Tags: javascript

В тег `<p>` записываеться текст, после этого при нажатии на кнопку надо весь текст в этом теге стереть, и поставить на это место новый. Пытался сделать так, но не вышло:

```
var ddd = document.getElementById("qqq");
ddd.innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А что не вышло?

```
<p id="tag">old text</p>
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('tag').innerHTML='new text';">
```

Comment: Хм... и правда затупил в коде извините, все работает